# How to set output html global lang attribute in Dokka?

Tags: android, javadoc, kdoc, kotlin-dokka

If I run the Dokka gradle script on a PC with English as system language, javadoc/kdoc html files have `<html lang="en">` at the top, but if I do it with the system language set to Spanish, it will replace it with `<html lang="es">` everywhere.

Is there an option in Dokka to set the preferred global content language for the output html? Thanks in advance.

I have looked in the official Dooka readme ([here](https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka)), but I don't see any option for this.